# What are all possible reasons for unlink to fail and how to check

Tags: php, file-permissions, file-exists, unlink

I would like a list or code block of all necessary checks needed to prevent and unlink function from throwing an error. The more detailed the better as I am hoping this question will solve a lot of peoples issues.

### Reasons for Errors

1. File doesn't exist
2. File Not Writable
3. Containing Directory Not Writable [@marc-anton-dahmen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198227/2273611)
4. File open/in use

This is what I have so far

```
if(is_actually_file($file)){ 

    if(is_writable($file) && is_writable(dirname($file))) {

        unlink($file);

    } else {

        // insufficient file permissions
    }

} else {
    // file doesn't exist
}


function is_actually_file($file){

    clearstatcache(true, $file);
    return is_file($file);
}
```

What other reasons are there for failing and how to check for them?

[unlink source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/250938e2d35fc54161a18167b7901c5e3b574371/ext/standard/file.c)

Comment: proper error handling will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`is_writable` includes a `file_exists` check. But you have to check if the containing directory is writable as well. 
This should do it:

```
if (is_writable($file) && is_writable(dirname($file))) {
    unlink($file);
} else {
    //...
}
```